# how to perform post method in windows 8 metro?

Tags: http-post, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have followed the HttpClient samples but couldn't figure it out how to post a method with 2 parameters.

Below is what I tried but it return bad gateway error:

```
        private async void Scenario3Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!TryUpdateBaseAddress())
        {
            return;
        }

        Scenario3Reset();
        Scenario3OutputText.Text += "In progress";

       string resourceAddress =  "http://music.api.com/api/search_tracks";
        try
        {
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        //    form.Add(new StringContent(Scenario3PostText.Text), "data");
            form.Add(new StringContent("Beautiful"), "track");
            form.Add(new StringContent("Enimem"), "artist");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, form);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            Scenario3OutputText.Text = hre.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // For debugging
            Scenario3OutputText.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I looked all over the internet, but couldn't find any working examples or documents that show how to perform the http post method. Any materials or samples would help me a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the server is expecting `multipart/form-data`? Have you tried `ByteArrayContent` that contains something like `artist=Enimem&track=Beautiful`?

Comment: I take it music.api.com isn't real, so I can't verify if it expects form data. But in general rest apis do not expect form-data. Form-data primarily used for user submitted forms and file uploads.

Comment: hmm, maybe I was wrong on the multipart/form, because that was the sample I found. If it's byteArray, how can i pass the parameters in? thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FormUrlEncodedContent instead of MultipartFormDataContent:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("track", "Beautiful"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("artist", "Enimem")
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to take the following approach where you set the POST data into the request content body.  Having to debug it is much easier!

Create your HttpClient object with the URL you're posting to:

```
string oauthUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
HttpClient theAuthClient = new HttpClient();
```

Form your request with the Post method to your url

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oauthUrl);
```

Create a content string with your parameters explicitly set in POST data format and set these in the request:

```
string content = "track=beautiful" +
  "&artist=eminem"+
  "&rating=explicit";

request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)));
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Send the request and get a response:

```
try
{                
    HttpResponseMessage response = await theAuthClient.SendAsync(request);
    handleResponse(response);
}
catch (HttpRequestException hre)
{

}
```

Your handler will be called once the request returns and will have response data from your POST.  The following example shows a handler that you could put a breakpoint into to see what the response content is, at that point, you could parse it or do whatever you need to do with it.

```
public async void handleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (content != null)
    {
        // put your breakpoint here and poke around in the data
    }
}
```